# Unable to Calculate Correct Average

Tags: c, floating-point, stdio

*C language, stdio.h library*

Sample code:

```
float avg;
avg = 3 / 2;
printf("Average: %.2f", avg);
```

From the code above I expect the following output:

```
Average = 1.50
```

But instead I get:

```
Average = 1.00
```

Why is this? And how do I get the correct output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
float avg;
avg = (float) 3 / 2;
printf("Average: %.2f", avg);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 3/2 is an integer division and that's why the answer is coming 1.00, convert 3 into float and then perform the division it will give the correct result

Answer (score 1):

3 and 2 are integers, so the resulting integer i.e. 1 will then cast to float after the division, and you will have 1.00.
you have to make them floats,
do this:

```
avg = 3.0 / 2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this..`avg=3.0/2.0` otherwise it's doing integer division. It's truncated to 1 otherwise. (Integer divison truncates, so any fractional part , here `.5` is discarded).

A decimal point in a constant indicates that it is floating point. So the result is not truncated.

From standard:-**§6.5.5.5**

> When integers are divided, the result of the / operator is the
>   algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing integer division there. So the fractional part is discarded.

Try this

```
float avg;
avg = 3.0 / 2;
printf("Average: %.2f", avg);
```

By keeping either the numerator or denominator of type float it will perform floating point division.